# Is there a debian package for the python module PyGLM?

Tags: python3, packaging

I am trying to [build](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/556611154/buildlog_ubuntu-impish-amd64.plots_0.5.1-1%7E202109030624%7Eubuntu21.10.1_BUILDING.txt.gz) a software in Launchpad, but I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'glm'
```

I found https://pypi.org/project/PyGLM/ but I could not find any package titled `python3-pyglm` in https://packages.ubuntu.com/.

Is this package available under some other name? Note that installing from pip is not an option while building in Launchpad.

Comment: glm.py .... could be `python3-pysal`  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=bionic&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=glm.py&searchon=contents

Comment: That [did not work](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/556642319/buildlog_ubuntu-focal-amd64.plots_0.5.1-2~202109031109~ubuntu20.04.1_BUILDING.txt.gz). This glm is probably something else, and it looks like the python glm module has not been packaged for Debian yet.

Comment: Well, you didn't tell which purpose glm is for, so it's still a blind guess : https://pypi.org/project/glm/ → → `pip3 install glm`

Comment: I found this library, but I am not sure if this is the one. I have asked the developer. https://github.com/alexhuntley/Plots/issues/26

Comment: Most likely it is this. https://pypi.org/project/PyGLM/, as the the package I am trying to build is meant to plot graphs using OpenGL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some research I see the following. ArchLinux AUR [has](https://repology.org/project/plots/versions) [PKGBUILD](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=plots-git) for [Plots](https://github.com/alexhuntley/Plots/) which mentions [python-pyglm](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/python-pyglm/).

So possible way to get newest Plots compiled is to create deb-package for PyGLM library first by:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install devscripts debhelper python3-all-dev python3-setuptools dh-python

cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/N0rbert/PyGLM.git
cd PyGLM
debuild -b -uc -us

sudo apt-get install ../python3-pyglm_2.3.1_amd64.deb
```

Alternatively, you an also use a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eapandada1/+archive/ubuntu/python3-pyglm) for `python3-pyglm`. This PPA can also be used as a dependency of other projects which require this package.

and then compile Plots on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as follows:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install devscripts debhelper python3-all-dev python3-setuptools dh-python python3-opengl libglib2.0-dev gobject-introspection python3-jinja2 python3-numpy python3-lark python3-pytest python3-freetype

cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/apandada1/Plots
cd Plots
debuild -b -uc -us

sudo apt-get install ../plots_0.5.1_all.deb
```

---

What is interesting - the [original 0.5.1 from Jan 28](https://github.com/alexhuntley/Plots/releases/tag/v0.5.1) compiles normally on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and 21.04 by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install devscripts debhelper python3-all-dev python3-setuptools dh-python python3-opengl libglib2.0-dev gobject-introspection python3-jinja2 python3-numpy python3-lark python3-pytest

cd ~/Downloads
wget https://github.com/alexhuntley/Plots/archive/v0.5.1.tar.gz
tar -xf v0.5.1.tar.gz
cd Plots-0.5.1/
debuild -b -uc -us
```

as it does not depend on PyGLM.

Comment: I am the maintainer of the PPA for plots. The current development version requires PyGLM, whose AUR package was created only today. Thank you for implementing the `debian/` directory for python3-pyglm. It would make my task easier.

Comment: You are welcome, as usual :)